# QSqlQuery returns "???" for none English string

Tags: linux, qt, unixodbc, qsqlquery

When running the code below the result is 'אבגדה' in Windows and '?????' on Linux, seems that 
the `qry.value(0)` (a QVarient type) using a defult coding. In Linux I'm using free.dts and odbc.ini in the driver level

**How to set QSqlQuery so that the return format will be UTF16?**

**What is the returned format?**

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("..."); //Some valid connection string

QByteArray ba;
char* _buffer11;

if(db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery qry(db);
    qry.prepare("Select UTF16 From DataTypes WHERE ID=9");

    if(qry.exec())
    {
        QVariantList resultList;

        while(qry.next())
        {
            resultList << qry.value(0);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the line `client charset = UTF-8` should be added to the `freetds.conf` file

```
[SERVER_1]
host     = 192.168.192.44
instance = SQLEXPRESS   
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```